# How to map to shared folder on Google Cloud Compute Engine Windows Server

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, network-drive, google-cloud-storage

I've set up Windows Server 2012 VM instance on Google cloud Compute Engine. I've set up a static IP for that server and I'm able to remote desktop in without problem. On the Windows Server, I've set up a sharing folder with the proper permissions.

Now, on my local PC running Win7 Ultimate, I'm trying to map a network a drive to that shared folder on the VM. What's the correct path to specific it to map to? I tried `\\<ip-address>\<shared-folder>` but it doesn't work.

Any other requirements to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

try to add firewall rules in the developers console; (to the default network)

**name;** default-allow-smb
**network;** default
**source filter;** allow from any source (0.0.0.0/0)
**allowed protocols and ports;** udp:137; udp:138; tcp:139; tcp:445

also allow all firewall rules on the windows server 2012 R2 to allow file -and printer sharing (open windows firewall with advanced security and allow outbound rules)

try if connecting to the server from the server is working; (showing shares);

```
\\ip-address
```

Comment: Does not work. I also tried to disable windows firewall, but it also did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing an SMB connction directly over the internet would be an enormous mistake,
unless you have absolutely no concerns about who on the planet can access your data.

I assume that Google has enacted measures to protect hosted sites against such
malpractices, and has blocked the SMB ports of 445 and 139.

The better way to do this under nearly all situations would be to configure a VPN.
A VPN will create a secure tunnel between the Google Compute site and your
internal network.
As the VPN is under your control, Google should not be able to intervene.

For more information, see the Google articles:

- [Cloud VPN overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview)
- [Choosing a VPN option](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/choosing-a-vpn)